# How to bind event in knockout.js in dynamically added content?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to add some content to my page after data binding, e.g.:

```
 $("<li>
       <div>text</div>
       <div  data-bind='event: { click: selectContact }'></div>
    </li>")
     .appendTo($("#userClientGroup")
     .find("#searched-client-ul-UCG"));
```

However, in this case the click event is not working; can any one can give me solution?

Comment: Why are you adding this dynamically?  I get the impression that you're trying to solve a symptom of the problem, but not the problem itself.

Comment: Well if you add content AFTER binding, it indeed won't bind to that content

Comment: @Smeegs I have to add content according to user search

Comment: @sroes yeh these the issue that i want to solve

Comment: You should add a "search" object to the ko observable including a bool to display/hide the markup you have in your question.  Then when search results are returned, update the observable with the search data and set the display/hide to true.  That way the markup will only show when there is search data, and will automatically update with the returned data.

Comment: Its a very large data i am not able to load all data and search will be not decided

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  But if you're loading the search data and creating the markup for it dynamically, this is literally no different.  But it doesn't break the view model.

Comment: If possible, you should go for Smeegs proposal. If that's not possible, you could maybe append the content BEFORE applying the binding. It that's also not possible, go check out @user3426870's answer.

Comment: ok then thanks let me check some another way

Comment: @SomeWhere if you don't use any of the suggested options, then you shouldn't be using knockout for the search results.  You should just add the markup as dynamic content.  To use a viewmodel, you need a model.

Comment: ok @Smeegs its means we are not able to change model after binding is done

Comment: No, you can update the model as long as it's an observable.  But you can't rebind once a container already has a binding.

Comment: ok thanks @Smeegs i appreciate your approach

Comment: Consider binding the List to an observableArray of results, and when the user searches, you update the items in results. Don't use jQuery to create elements; let knockout handle that.

Comment: Could you please post more code - I can almost guarantee that you can add it with Knockout and catch the click event with Knockout as well. (The code posted looks 'wrong')

Comment: @RuneJeppesen Please give me your suggestion in your code

Comment: @SomeWhere could you please give more information about your problem 1. what exactly has a lot of data? 2. Why not use the click KO-binding? 3. Is it just one place you append this li?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ko.applybindings(viewModel, $('#yourNewElement'))`.Just be careful not to try binding an element already bound, or you'll have an error.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to avoid using jQuery (or any DOM method) to append new elements, in order to avoid having to bind your viewmodel against these elements. You can solve the problem either with existing bindings in your HTML or with a custom binding, or a combination. Your bindings should handle the DOM manipulation, not your other code (which shouldn't need to be aware of the DOM).

Another approach is to use a delegated event handler. I use the following custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.delegatedEvent = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {},
            setupEventHandler = function (settings) {
                if (settings.data) {
                    $(element).on(settings.event, settings.target, settings.data, settings.handler);
                } else {
                    $(element).on(settings.event, settings.target, settings.handler);
                }

                ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                    $(element).off(settings.event, settings.target, settings.handler);
                });
            };

        if ($.isArray(options)) {
            $.each(options, function () {
                setupEventHandler(this);
            });
        } else {
            setupEventHandler(options);
        }
    }
};
```

Use this on the `<ul>` you're inserting the `li` into as such:

```
<ul data-bind="delegatedEvent: { event: click, target: '.contact-select', handler: selectContact }">
```

Add the class in your original insertion code, and remove the data-bind there.

```
$('<li><div>text</div><div class="contact-select"></div></li>')
 .appendTo($("#userClientGroup").find("#searched-client-ul-UCG"));
```

Not only have you solved the problem, but you've replaced potentially lots of event handlers with just one.